# Ruby Output every possible character (A-Z, a-z, 0-9) combination between 8 and 16 characters long

Tags: arrays, ruby, combinations, permutation

How would one go about outputting every single possible character combination (Between 8 and 16) using the characters A-Z (Upper and Lowercase) and numbers 0-9 while also using a few special characters such as underscores and dollar signs.

Comment: How many years do you have to run this program? There are 62^16 possibilities here. That's about 1.5 trillion years at a billion iterations per second.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What effort have you put into this besides asking here? Is this an assignment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @tadman said, this will not complete within the lifetime of our solar system, but in theory, you could accomplish it like this:

```
chars = [*:A..:Z, *:a..:z, *0..9, ?$, ?_]

(8..16).each do |n|
  chars.permutation(n) do |a|
    puts a.join
  end
end
```

If you want to calculate the number of lines of output before beginning:

```
(8..16).reduce(0) {|sum,n| sum + chars.permutation(n).size }
```

Note: There are four `Array` methods for getting "combinations" of characters: [`permutation`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-permutation), [`combination`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-combination), [`repeated_permutation`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-repeated_permutation), and [`repeated_combination`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-repeated_combination). You should check the documentation or experiment with each to ensure you're getting the right set of "combinations."